# Puppeteer multiple browsers or pages

Tags: puppeteer, headless-browser

I am trying to crawl about 50 pages with puppeteer, and right now I am doing one after another in a single browser, single page. To make this faster, should I use more pages or more browsers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227893/multi-browsers-vs-multi-tabs-in-puppeteer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use either:

- Using more pages isn't great because your browser will build up a history. This may not be what you intend.
- Using more browsers isn't great because creating a new browser is a fairly expensive operation.

I think you want to use [Browser Contexts](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-class-browsercontext). Think of a browser context as an incognito window - you can open it quickly, but it doesn't share history, cookies, etc. with other contexts.

Comment: could you explain your first bullet point a little more? Does it apply to me if I don't login or anything

Comment: It's perhaps less relevant if you're not logging in or doing anything which would create a "state" - although even if you believe your activity is stateless, the browser will still create a cache, accept cookies, etc. This could cause a problem (e.g. if you're writing tests and accidentally create a dependency on the order that the tests are being run), so _in general_ browser contexts are what you want to use.