# Azure Kubernetes - Puppeteer preparing PDF Error: Page crashed! at Page._onTargetCrashed

Tags: kubernetes, puppeteer, azure-aks

When program runs `await page.evaluate(...);`, there is error throwing out:

```
Error: Page crashed!
    at Page._onTargetCrashed (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:170:24)
    at CDPSession.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:125:56)
    at CDPSession.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at CDPSession._onMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:200:12)
    at Connection._onMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:112:17)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:41:24)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:203:13)
[2019-09-19T02:59:56.202Z] Error for printPdf()
Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:183:56
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:182:12)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:106:44)
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:48:31)
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
    at DOMWorld.evaluate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:112:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:110:27)
    at Page.evaluate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:782:43)
    at Page.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
    at printPdf (/usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:219:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
    at async /usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:133:21 {
  message: 'Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.'
}
```

I tried to increase Azure Kubernetes VM size to have better CPU and Memory, it worked and problem was gone.
However, it happened suddenly again and I don't want to upgrade VM size to EXTREMELY model.

How to solve it completely?

---

Further adding htop screen capture for reference:
(It was not reaching to 80% yet)
[image]

Comment: What url are you trying to render with `puppeteer`? Which is your environment?

Comment: Hi @Yasen, the URL is local URL index.html with calling my JS functions to do render for PDF content. In my case, I tried to prepare 600 photos for rendering and faced error. Environments both Production and Staging.

Comment: Are you hitting [resource limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57295869/5627599) regarding CPU/memory? How many browsers, pages, etc. are you starting?

Comment: Hi @ThomasDondorf, I deploy 4 pods on 4CPU with 8GB Memory VM (Checked "Allocatable Resource" only ~ 3xxx m & 5.x GB) So, I assigned 850m with 1.2Gi for each pod. if there are 600 photos, around 50 pages in PDF. (but when printing PDF, program will render all components to calculate the height then make the line break, maybe there is problem). However, when I used commands `kubectl top pods` and `kubectl top nodes`, checked CPU and Memory were not used up to 100% yet.

Comment: Added htop screen capture for reference.

Comment: @DaiKeung Not used up to 100%, but close? CPU/memory might still be the problem then. Maybe you can [parallelize the jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52233124/5627599)?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDondorf. Your package may work but I would not test it under company's restriction. Sorry that I am not allow to download 3rd party code which is not used widely. Do you have other solutions?

Comment: @DaiKeung am facing the same issue, how did u fix it?

Comment: @palAlaa I just upgrade machine with better CPU, then solved it.